# Error when connecting to shared Windows Printers

Tags: windows-server-2008, print-server, shared-printers

I'm replacing our Windows 2003 print server with one running on Windows 2008 R2. I have connected and configured all of our printers and can successfully print to them from the server itself. All of the printers are shared and user's have permission to print on all of them.

Whenever one of our clients attempts to connect through the shares they receive the following error message:

> Operation could not be completed (error 0x0000709). Double check the printer name and make sure that the printer is connected to the network.

No messages are generated on the client Event Log nor is anything generated on the server.

I have reinstalled the drivers as suggested by a few forum posts I came across and it didn't solve the issue. There are twelve different printer drivers and they are all experiencing this issue so I believe it is unrelated to the driver.

I have disabled UAC on both the client and server since that has caused so many headaches before, but it too did not solve this problem. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: What port is selected on the `Ports` table of the printer properties dialog on the client machines?

Comment: On the server it shows the IP address, the client can not connect to the printers at all (they never make it to the local list of printers) and thus I can't check what clients see

Answer (score 1):

Are  your clients running 32 bit OS?
If yes have you installed the 32 bit Print drivers as well?

Comment: I have both 32 and 64 bit drivers installed for most drivers, I've tried from 32 and 64 bit machines running Windows 7, 64 bit version of Server 2003 (The error is slightly different: "Operation could not be completed. Either the printer name was typed incorrectly, or the specified printer has lost its connection to the server.")